# click anywhere on the page and the popover should disappear

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Icon that if you click on it a popover appears with some data populated from a webservice. but the problem is I want the popover appears whenever I click on it and **disappears whenever I click anywhere else on the page**!

Could you please let me know how I can do that?

PS:I already tried trigger:'manual' but it did not work for my example!

My code here:

```
$('#myIcon').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myURL"
            }).done(function (data) {                                           
                $this.popover({
                    placement:'bottom',                                        
                    content: function () {
                        html = "<table class='table table-bordered ' id='myTbl'><tbody id='myTblBody'>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            html = html + "<tr><td>" + data[i]['username'] + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        html = html + "</tbody></html>";
                        return html;
                    },
                    html: true,
                })
            });
});
```

Comment: Can you actually read your own code ?

Comment: @Virus721 It's oddly indented, but not all that bad. If you're going to take the time to snark about it, why don't you take a little more and suggest some ways in which it might be improved?

Comment: Probably because i care as much about the question as the asker cares about the time and patience it's gonna take us to read it.

Comment: but still I don't know how I can edit my code! As Aaron said if you let me know now how to edit my code here (if there is any short key which orders my code), next time both of us will be happier! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try if this works for you.

When you show the popover, add a one-time click listener to the whole body which hides the popover.

```
$('#myIcon').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myURL"
            }).done(function (data) {                                           
                $this.popover({
                    placement:'bottom',                                        
                    content: function () {
                        html = "<table class='table table-bordered ' id='myTbl'><tbody id='myTblBody'>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            html = html + "<tr><td>" + data[i]['username'] + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        html = html + "</tbody></html>";
                        return html;
                    },
                    html: true,
                });
                $('body').one('click',function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    $this.popover('hide');
                });
            });
});
```

Comment: Nice man! It works perfectly!Also in order to show the popover I need to double click the icon (one for ajax call and one for popover I assume) can I change it in a way that popover appears with one click?

Comment: @ShimaMdz i've never used popover, but you could try $this.popover('show'); after your $this.popover({....});

Answer (score 0):

`popover` has a method named as `hideOnHTMLClick` which says `Hide popovers when clicked outside of them.`

```
$('#myIcon').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myURL"
            }).done(function (data) {                                           
                $this.popover({
                    placement:'bottom',
                    hideOnHTMLClick: true,                                        
                    content: function () {
                        html = "<table class='table table-bordered ' id='myTbl'><tbody id='myTblBody'>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            html = html + "<tr><td>" + data[i]['username'] + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        html = html + "</tbody></html>";
                        return html;
                    },
                    html: true,
                })
            });
});
```

Comment: Also in order to show the popover I need to double click the icon (one for ajax call and one for popover I assume) can I change it in a way that popover appears with one click?